# jQuery sort removes element innerText

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html-lists

I was happily writing a widget, when suddenly IE (7-9) ruined my day.
Widget at some part hides a select box, makes a div, ul inside and fills it with li according to select options. Also my widget sorts the values, and here comes the problem. IE removes all innerText from list elements, so it shows n blank <li />.
Any idea how to fix that? That is really annoying :(. Here is a link to jsfiddle with the example: http://jsfiddle.net/g8Cd6/
And the code:
HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="picked">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
    <option>e</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery.fn.pick = function(sort) {
    console.log("pick_v2");
    var pick = this;
    this.widget = $('<div class="pick widget"></div>').insertAfter(this);
    this.list = $('<ul class="pick list"></ul>');
    this.widget.append(this.list);
    this.host = $(this).hide();
    var opts = this.host.children();

    for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
        this.list.append('<li>' + opts.eq(i).text() + '</li>');
    }

    this.sort = function(container) {
        var my_options = container.children();
        my_options.sort(function(a,b) {
            if ($(a).text() > $(b).text()) return 1;
            else if ($(a).text() < $(b).text()) return -1;
            else return 0;
        });
        container.html("");
        for (var i = 0; i < my_options.length; i++) {
            console.log(my_options[i].innerText)
            container.append( my_options[i] );
        }
    };
    pick.sort(this.list);
};

$("#picked").pick(true);
```

Thanks in advice,
Dracco

Comment: It's work for me without `container.html("");`

Comment: I've put it there, because of rest of the function, but replacing it with .empty() works like a charm. Thanks!